# Sending image over network using sockets, messed up data

Tags: c#, image, sockets, transfer

I'm having trouble sending the folowing 140kb image file over the network using sockets:

[image: original image]

The beginning of the file gets transfered correctly, then the rest gets messed up leading to the following result:

[image: messed up image]

I have a server, that waits for files and a client that connects to server and starts the file tranfer. When client closes the connection, server knows that the file has been done sending and saves it.

All the data on the server side is being collected in byte list (GLOBAL.FILE_BUFFER), before written to a file:

```
public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        try
        {
                SocketPacket socketData = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState; 
                int iRx = socketData.m_currentSocket.EndReceive(asyn);

                for (int f = 0; f < iRx; f++)
                {
                    GLOBAL.FILE_BUFFER.Add(socketData.dataBuffer[f]); // Collect all the incoming data into a buffer
                }

                WaitForData(socketData.m_currentSocket, socketData.socket_id, REQUEST_INDEX_ID);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {

        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {

        }
    }
```

This is the code I'm using to write to a file:

```
     public static void ByteArrayToFile(string _FileName, byte[] _ByteArray, int BytesRead)
     {
         System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(_FileName,  System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
         _FileStream.Write(_ByteArray, 0, BytesRead);
         _FileStream.Close();
     }
```

I used the same ByteArrayToFile function on cient side and it saved the image correctly. It appears that client is sending the correct data, but when server recieves it, it gets messed up. I saved file on both ends, by client and by server and then compared them:

[image]

Notice the purple line/bar in the bottom center. It indicates that data doesn't match there, but notice that it matches perfectly at the beginning..

I don't understand how can this happen since I'm using list and simply keep adding to the byte list until there's nothing left to read!? If you don't have solution can you give me any tips please?! This problem has been bugging me for weeks, would love to get it figured out finaly. Thanks!

Comment: Have you verified the data in the byte[] you send is the same as the byte[] generated by the image?  Post the code that generates the byte[]

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. The client fetches the image from the web, then uploads it to the server. When I collect all the data in byte list on client side from httpwebresponse, I save the image, to verify that it's valid and it gets saved and works. Please let me know if that was your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell from your data comparison what the problem is?  Is the server simply dropping bytes or is the data corrupted?  How much data is transferred correctly?

Consider using something like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) to examine the bytes as they come off the wire.  That should help you determine whether it's a network error or something in your server code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. From what I can tell first 40% gets transfared correctly, then from there most of the data is messed and not simply in segments (like first 1024 bytes ok, then rest messed) but it gets messed on a byte level, like 10 bytes ok, two bytes don't match etc..

Comment: also, if I test with a larger image, a smaller percentage gets sent correctly and the rest is messed. Almost seems like the first segment (1024 bytes) are always perfect but then it messes it up afterwards which is weird..

Comment: You might want to try printing the receive buffer size (`iRx`) when you get a packet.  If this correlates to the point where data corruption begins, then it's possible you're dropping data while copying to your file buffer.